# Running the code of J-Linkage for model fitting

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to run the Matlab code of J-Linkage algorithm from here: http://www.diegm.uniud.it/fusiello/demo/jlk/

However, I am getting the following error to run it:

Undefined function 'pDistJaccard' for input arguments of type 'logical'.

Error in clusterPoints (line 27)

Y = pDistJaccard(totdbin');

Error in testJLinkage (line 25)

[T, Z, Y, totdbin] = clusterPoints(totd, inliersThreshold);

I didn't change anything in the code & I am using windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of the function is included in the folder 'CSources'. It is coded using a mex function so you need to compile in Matlab. Refer to the function 'mex'